# How to stop GPS on Android app when not in use

Tags: java, android, gps, locationlistener

I have created an app that displays the user location on google maps using LocationListener and GPS. I'm trying to turn GPS off when the user navigates away from the app, but everything I try doesn't work, I can still see the GPS icon active at the top of the screen. At present I have:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // Turning off
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    locationManager = null;

}
```

help please :(

Comment: Sorted it! Twas the onResume.

Answer (score 2):

Try Your test over Device. If using device uninstall your application and restart your device and install again.

make sure the listener you are removing is the same for which you requested updates.
it should work then.

Comment: I have tried this. I had to because I have been working on it for a few days, and didn't want my phone to be running GPS the whole time.

Comment: Here is the line I am using to request updates: locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it!

It turned out the problem was in my onResume with these two lines:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationListener = new GPSLocationListener();
```

I never bothered looking at them because I didn't expect the onResume state to be affecting the onPause.

Thanks for your help Javanator.

Hope this helps someone else :)